# What does A=A~=0 do and how do I specify it?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I've been working with segmentation of a CT-Picture and somewhere came over this formula:

A=A~=0

In my case is A a huge matrix with values from 0 to 255. If I use A=A~=0, where A is my matrix, do I get all values that are 0 to 0 (false) and the rest to 1 (true). So does this formula say something like "Is the value NOT equal to 0?".

Yet another question, if what I wrote before is true, is it posible to turn the formula into a few number, such as "Is the value NOT equal to 0,1,2,3,4,5,...,50?"

Hope my question is understandable and that someone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`~=` is the "not equals" operator.

So the expression  `A ~= 0` returns a logical matrix with entries "1" where A(i,j) is non-zero (and zero in all other entries).

The result is assigned back to A so you get a sort of a mask: A(i,j) == 1 if A had non zero value at this point.

Comment: The operation in question is performed via linear indexing, so `A` need not be a 2-D matrix as your example suggests. `A` may be a vector (also considered a matrix in Matlab), an N-D array, or an empty array. Additionally, if `A` is an empty array of some form, e.g., `[]`, `A` itself is returned – rather than `0` (`false`) or `1` (`true`) - something to always watch out for.

Comment: @horchler: +1. Thanks for the detailed information. I didn't want to bother what seemed to be a newbie with N-D arrays but you are correct, of course. Feel free to to edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your first question is thoroughly [answered by @nimrodm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19255109/1292374), however for the second part you have two different approaches. If you want to exclude all numbers in a specified interval like `[0, 50]` you can use

```
A = (A<0) | (A>50);
```

If you are checking for some specific values, say, `{0, 5, 11, 50}` you can use `ismember`

```
A = ~ismember(A, [0, 5, 11, 50]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For `~=` your understanding is correct, you'll get 0 for 0's and 1's for all not equal to 0.

Regarding your second question, have a matrix

`B = [0:50]; % or whatever elements in it;`

then use `arrayfun` command

`A=arrayfun(@(x)(ismember(x,B)),A);`

Type: `help arrayfun` and `help ismember` at command window for details.

Basically it searches of presence of each element from `A` in `B` using an anonymous function.